# Whether to delete or edit my previously asked questions

Tags: discussion

I am currently under a ban for asking questions on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com due to some of my previous questions so I need to clarify a couple of things.

This question. [Nav walker class error on WordPress update](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224069/nav-walker-class-error-on-wordpress-update). has got 0 votes and 0 answers.

And this one, [is_home , is_front_page not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189911/is-home-is-front-page-not-working), -1 votes but 3 answers and 7k views.

I know that my questions were not good enough or not clear enough to understand. But what should I do to get my ban removed as editing them now won't make a difference as they were asked a lot of time ago.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's ever a case where you should delete a question that has an answer.

Here's what I suggest to ensure you don't get banned from asking questions:

1) **Stay on topic.**
**All** 3rd party plugins are considered to be off-topic since you would need prior knowledge of the plugin to answer the question. Questions regarding 3rd party plugin code or issues are better directed through their specific support channels.

2) **Answer and accept your own answers to your own questions if possible.**
 Some of your questions you've already answered either through help from the comments or as an actual answer. I suggest going back and giving questions you feel you've answered a checkmark or anything that's been fixed in the comments try to give an answer that may give a future reader a better understanding of how to solve a similar issue ( and checkmark that as well ). There is a time limit on how long an answer to your own question needs to be up before it can be checkmarked to avoid any malicious behavior but once that time passes there's no reason not to.

3) **Phrase your question in such a way that answers may help other users.**
How you phrase a question is sometimes just as important as the question itself. This comes with practice and time, viewing other well received questions on the site may give you a better idea of what I mean.

---

Feel free to go back and edit your questions or answers to make them clearer. There's no time limit on editing your questions or answers. Go back and make them better, cleaner, clearer. For questions that don't have answers it will bump them to the front-page where they may get more attention ( though, don't do this for the sake of bumping... ) and it will make it overall easier for future readers to understand and future users to answer.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee.....thank you. I will try to accomplish the above mentioned points. Hope the ban gets lifted soon :)...